# Hadoop, how to get Input file name in OutputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I have a map only job and custom OutputFormat that extends FileOutputFormat and want to write output files with the same name(or slightly modified) as input. So I need to get the file name in my custom RecordWriter. I know that this is possible in Mapper via this code:

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

But have no idea how to pass filename from mapper to my RecordWriter.

Comment: You have multiple mappers for multiple files and write the output with common key. From reduce side, process record with common key. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MultipleOutputFormat as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqfrgnMIkqw&index=51&list=PLf0swTFhTI8p7ZYBB5DmRHK3L6aq8Mvcv)

You need pass desired string file name from mapper to reducer using context/configuration object.